# Determine version of AWS tools using only powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

Using powershell (no gui) how can I find out which version of AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell I'm using?

more:

I'm using powershell remoting and AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell to download a file from S3. I'm having trouble setting credentials, [this aws powershell reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html) states that:

> In versions of the Tools for Windows PowerShell that are older than 1.1, the Set-AWSCredentials command did not work correctly

But I don't know what version of AWS tools I'm using. There doesn't seem to be an obvious command to try, for example, the Read-S3Object command -Version parameter is used to determine the version of the S3 object being downloaded, not the version of the AWS tools.

It's possible I could figure it out by using RDP and the add/remove programs gui, but that's a different question, this server is suposed to be administered using powershell remoting only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inspect the module via [`Get-Module`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849700.aspx).

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name AWSPowerShell

    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell

  ModuleType Version    Name            ExportedCommands
  ---------- -------    ----            ----------------
  Binary     3.1.75.0   AWSPowerShell   {Clear-AWSHistory, Set-AWSHistoryConfiguration....
```

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, the AWS Tools for PowerShell themselves have a cmdlet to grab the cmdlet version, Get-AWSPowerShellVersion. This returns the version of both the installed module and the installed .NET SDK.

**Example:**

```
PS C:/> Get-AWSPowerShellVersion

AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell
Version 3.1.95.0
Copyright 2012-2016 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

Amazon Web Services SDK for .NET
Core Runtime Version 3.1.10.0
Copyright 2009-2015 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

Release notes: https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/PowerShell

This software includes third party software subject to the following copyrights:
- Logging from log4net, Apache License
[http://logging.apache.org/log4net/license.html]
```

**Documentation:**

- [Cmdlet Reference - Get-AWSPowerShellVersion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-AWSPowerShellVersion.html)